# Loading xib window from status menu

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I have MainMenu.Xib which has a status menu element.  The MainMenu File Owner is mapped to AppDelegate.

I also have another Xib which is a Window and it's File Owner is mapped to a ViewController with the same name.

So what I have tried and it kind of works is I have created an action in the appDelegate and have mapped the menu item in the status menu to the action in the appDelete using the First Responder.

In the action I have put:

```
SubscriptionsViewController *vc = [[SubscriptionsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Subscriptions" bundle:nil];
[vc view];
```

If I step through the code it the window shows up but then goes away.  So I have two questions

1) I thought there was a way to load the xib with NSMenuItem without the need of the above code.

2) How do I keep the window from closing right away?  Do I need to save the view pointer or something?

edit: format code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) I thought there was a way to load the xib with NSMenuItem without the need of the above code.

Since NSWindow is not inherited from NSView like in iOS (UIWindow:UIView), it makes no sense to use NSViewController to load window from a xib. Use subclass of NSObject instead.

```
@interface SubscriptionsViewController : NSObject

    @property (assign, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;

@end


@implementation SubscriptionsViewController

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {

       [NSBundle loadNibNamed:@"Subscriptions" owner:self];

    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

> 2) How do I keep the window from closing right away? Do I need to save the view pointer or something?

- It depends on the context to retain the instance of subscriptionsViewController or not. You can use below code to display a window, where the instance of window is in nib -

  ```
     self.subscriptionsViewController = [[SubscriptionsViewController alloc] init];
     [self.subscriptionsViewController.window makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
  ```

Remember if "Visible At Launch" is set in nib, then the window is visible when you instantiate subscriptionsViewController.

Comment: MYCentralViewController suppose to be SubscriptionsViewController?

Answer (score 0):

You may add your window into the MainMenu.xib instead of using an addition xib file and create an outlet in the AppDelegare.h as

```
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
```

Then all you need to do is

```
window.isVisible = !window.isVisible;
```

in the necessary action method...

Comment: I initially did that but this window is going to a ton of logic in it and didn't want it littering the appdelegate. So I wanted to seperate it out.

Comment: Then, for sure you will need to initiate the xib file as you did in your example...